# What is the best way to perform join table mapping with 3 columns?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, dropwizard, join

Please find attached Entity relationship diagram and please suggest me best possible solution.[image]

I hope my ERD relationship is good for this case.

Here, what i did so far ? Followed : [Giannigar’s blog](https://giannigar.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/mapping-a-many-to-many-join-table-with-extra-column-using-jpa/)

What is the best way to perform such a mapping? These are my Entity classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t")
public class T
{
    //… other fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "t", targetEntity = TMJoin.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<TMJoin> tmJoins = new ArrayList<TMJoin>();

//… setter/getter methods
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "m")
public class M
{
    //… other fields 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "m", targetEntity = TMJoin.class)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<TMJoin> tmJoins = new ArrayList<TMJoin>();

    //… setter/getter methods
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "u")
public class U {

    //… other fields 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "u", targetEntity = TMJoin.class)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<TMJoin> tmJoins = new ArrayList<TMJoin>();

    //… setter/getter methods
}


@Entity
@Table(name= "t_m_join")
public class TMJoin
{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "tMJoinSeq", sequenceName = "seq_t_m_join_id", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "tMJoinSeq")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=T.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)      
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name="t_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) })   
    @JsonBackReference
    private T t;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=U.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)     
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name="u_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) })
    @JsonManagedReference
    private U u;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=M.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)     
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name="m_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) })
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JsonProperty("m")
    private M m;

//… setter/getter methods
}
```

Maybe there is some more good way to do such join table mapping with additional reference column?

EDIT: 
I am getting error while going to save T object.

```
web_1 | ERROR [2016-04-13 15:54:09,619] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 2270a7a8addbc3e7
web_1 | ! java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (com.core.TMJoin)
```

Comment: With my experience I'll say there's no better way to implement this datamodel. I suppose there's no better way to model your data either, is there?

Comment: I feel like table relationship is bit hacky, is this hacky or good ?

Comment: Yes, it seems a bit hacky but from the point of view of data modelling your image seems to be right. But sometimes data modelling has to be done based on how you are going to use stored data. Maybe you can join 2 of the tables in 1, although you might have repeated data, it would simplify model and JPA implementation.

Comment: yeah, i did that before, It's repeating data. So changed to this.

Comment: If you remove the join table, what is the relationship you are expecting between the entities? This question cannot be answered without knowing what your use cases are.

Comment: I have data in join table. One T can have one or more M saved by one or more U. Data like (T1-U1-M1, T1-U1-M2, T2-U1-M1, and so on...)